# How can I select the "maximum" row from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

How can I select the maximum row from a table?  What does maximum mean -- well my table has two timestamp columns, TIME1 and TIME2.  The maximum column is the one with the latest value for TIME1.  If that is not a unique row, then the maximum is the one within those rows with the latest value for TIME2.

This is on Oracle if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a "Top-N" query:

> select * from (
>       select * from table
>        order by time1 desc, time2 desc
>     ) where rownum < 2;

if you properly index on time1, time2 it will be very fast:

http://blog.fatalmind.com/2010/07/30/analytic-top-n-queries/

Comment: Why is this marked correct? It orders by time1,time2 ASCENDING, which means the opposite of "the latest value for time".

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: Oh yes, thank you.  If someone edits I'll mark it correct again.